# What does it mean when I can't "use method return value in write context"?

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I use this statement `if(count($this->input->post('p_id') =0))`, I keep getting this error:

```
    Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\CI\professional_ci\application\models\MProducts.php  on line 249
```

But when I use `if(count($this->input->post('p_id')))`, it works. What does it mean I can't use method return?

Comment: Upload some god damn code of MProducts.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first line you're trying to assign the value 0 to the function count. What you should use is == to test for equality.

```
if(count($this->input->post('p_id'))==0)
```

Comment: Aye. The root cause of this error pops up in most languages for most programmers at one point or another. Some IDEs will even try and point this out to you.